# Why am I getting this value?

Tags: c#, double

I've got the following:

```
var deltaTvd = stationTwo.VerticalDepth - stationOne.VerticalDepth;
```

Now, `stationTwo.VerticalDepth` is 10646.51 and `stationOne.VerticalDepth` is `10580.52`. When I subtract these, I get `65.99`. However, Visual Studio shows the answer as `65.989999999999782`. The `VerticalDepth` property is a `double`. I'm wondering why I get the extra decimal places instead of just the `65.99`?

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic.  At least one of those three numbers can't be stored with perfect precision in a double.

Comment: Dupe of about 10,000 StackOverflow questions.  Take your pick.

Comment: Consider casting your values to decimal to avoid these mathematical shenanigans.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net